# How to filter groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this

```
A  B
1  1
1  2
1  3
2  2
2  1 
3  2
3  3
3  4
```

I would like to extract rows whose col B is not ascending like

```
A B
2 2
2 1
```

I tried

```
df.groupby("A").filter()...
```

But I stacked to extract.

If you have any solution,please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`pandas.Series.is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic.html):

```
df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x:not x.is_monotonic)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B
3  2  2
4  2  1
```

Comment: are there any way to fix it?

Comment: KeyError: '[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  1.  1.  1.] not in index'

Comment: What is the output of `df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x:not x.is_monotonic)`?

Comment: Out[27]:

0       0.0

1       0.0

2       0.0

3       0.0

4       0.0

5       0.0

6       0.0

7       0.0

8       0.0

Comment: That's really odd given that `pd.Series.is_monotonic` returns `bool`. I'm afraid I cannot help you without further information about your data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and compare by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for at least one negative value with [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().lt(0).any())]
print (df1)
   A  B
3  2  2
4  2  1
```